# If $g_i\in K[Y_1,\dots,Y_m]$, is $(X_1-g_1,\dots,X_n-g_n)\cap k[Y_1,\dots,Y_m]=0$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

For $k$ a field, suppose $g_i\in k[Y_1,\dots,Y_m]$. If $I=(X_1-g_1,\dots,X_n-g_n)$ is the generated ideal in $k[X_1,\dots,X_n,Y_1,\dots,Y_m]$, is it true that 
$$(X_1-g_1,\dots,X_n-g_n)\cap k[Y_1,\dots,Y_m]=0?$$

I'm curious because any $f\in k[X_1,\dots,X_n,Y_1,\dots,Y_m]$ can be written in the form $f=g+h$ where $g\in I$, and $h\in k[Y_1,\dots,Y_m]$ be expanding instances of $X_i$ as $(X_i-g_i)+g_i$, and I suspect this decomposition is unique.

Putting a monomial order $X_1>X_2>\dots>X_n>Y_1>\dots>Y_m$, it is true in the case $n=1$, since if $h_1\neq 0$, then $h_1(X_1-g_1)$ will have a leading term divisible by $X_1$, since the leading term of $h_1X_1$ will not cancel with anything in $h_1g_1$, so is not in $k[Y_1,\dots,Y_m]$. But I don't see if this generalizes for $n>1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  As is often the case, the easiest way to see this is to construct a homomorphism: there is a homomorphism $F:k[X_1,\dots,X_n,Y_1,\dots,Y_m]\to k[Y_1,\dots,Y_m]$ fixing $k[Y_1,\dots,Y_m]$ and mapping $X_i$ to $g_i$.  Clearly $\ker F$ contains $(X_1-g_1,\dots,X_n-g_n)$ but does not contain any nonzero element of $k[Y_1,\dots,Y_m]$, and thus $(X_1-g_1,\dots,X_n-g_n)\cap k[Y_1,\dots,Y_m]=0.$

Comment: Thanks, much faster than trying to expand and see if terms cancel.